# Equivalent of Constructor code in visual C# Complex

Tags: c#, java, class, constructor

Hello guys I was searching in the web how to achieved this java code in C# but I have no luck. I have created a superclass and a base class with arguments Can anyone help me. I want to achieved this code in C#.

```
class People
{
    public String first_name;

    public String last_name;

    public People(String fname, String lname)
    {
        this.first_name = fname;

        this.last_name = lname;
    }
}

class Student extends People
{
    Public int studentID;

    public Student(String fname,String lname,int studid)
    {
       super(fname,lname);

       this.studentID = studid;
    }

}

 Student newStud = new Student('Jessica','Doe','123);
```

here is the code  i want to achieved in c#, instead of calling the people class and instantiating it, i just want to call the student class that inherits from people class. I'm new in C# guys can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Please clarify your question. I'm guessing that you're looking for the equivalent of `super()` or `extends` in C#, but you don't make this clear in your post.

Comment: It is also important to note that as per `C#` naming conventions, public members should be `ProperCased`, so it would be `public string FirstName` and `public string LastName` (as opposed to the horrible java convention)

Comment: It also wouldn't be `class People`, because usually class names are singular, therefore it'd be `class Person`.

Comment: Yes i was looking for the equivalent of super() in c#, im new in c#. I was planning to create a simple program that has student and faculty staff. since students has different fields for example student has a course,id,subject field etc. and faculty has different field as well. I just wanted to inherit the common fields from people class. Guys thanks for answering my question so far i still havnt found the solution to my problem.

Comment: In my answer I changed the horrible java convention to something smooth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this:

```
abstract class People
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;

    public People(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
}

sealed class Student : People
{
    public int StudentId;

    public Student(string firstName, string lastName, int studendId)
        : base(firstName, lastName) //Calling the base class constructor
    {
        StudentId = studendId;
    }
}
```

Comment: please edit your answer and improve the indentation for clarity.

Comment: Why do you use abstract?

Comment: The abstract modifier indicates that the thing being modified has a missing or incomplete implementation. The abstract modifier can be used with classes, methods, properties, indexers, and events. Use the abstract modifier in a class declaration to indicate that a class is intended only to be a base class of other classes. Members marked as abstract, or included in an abstract class, must be implemented by classes that derive from the abstract class.

Comment: I know what is abstract, but i dont clearly understand, why do you added it for this class. Why do you think that the people can't be initated for example. Furthermore in the question,there is nothing about that, but i thank the aim is the equivaletion with the asked java classes. No offensive, i just try understand your thing

Comment: It was more of a hint to mark it abstract if it is only inherited from and as far as the question goes, it is. The student class could also be sealed I guess.

Answer (score 1):

It is too simple, as i think

```
class People
{
    public String first_name;
    public String last_name;

    public People(string fname, string lname)
    {
        this.first_name = fname;
        this.last_name = lname;
    }
}

class Student : People
{
    public int studentID;
    public Student(string fname, string lname, int studid): base(fname,lname)
    {
        this.studentID = studid;
    }
}
```